# Silverlight datagrid load all rows

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

The Silverlight datagrid seems to load rows (firing off the LoadingRow event) while I scroll up and down.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I would like to load **all** rows at once when I set the datagrid's ItemSource.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely happening because SL datagrid uses virtualization for performance optimization. You can read more here, but it appears the solution is to add this to your DG declaration:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason it does this. A datagrid in Silverlight automatically resizes itself. Only loading part of the data source does increase performance. Is is rather big deal if you have a lot of row, that is a lot of work for your GPU.